# ERROR: No results. Previous SQL was not a query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver="{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}", server="xxx", database="yy", user="abc", password="abc")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

b = alter table temp1 add column3 varchar(10)
cursor.execute(b)
cursor.fetchall()
```

from the above code I'm trying to alter the table and add the column as i contain 2 tables 1 is existing table and the other is new table the column from the new table as to be added to the exixting table so i have done the code but i got the error of

> ERROR: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

so please help me out to clear this error.

Comment: `b = "alter table temp1 add column3 varchar(10)"` ? (use quotes).

Comment: Why are you using `fetchall` here? You can't *fetch* a result set from a query that returns no result set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line of code to as below

`b = 'alter table temp1 add column3 varchar(10);'`

this assigns the entire SQL command as string to the variable b, which then you can use in the call to `execute()` function of the cursor.
Also, the `ALTER TABLE` SQL statement will not return any results set, so you need not call `fetchXX()` method after executing it.

Comment: it got executed successfully but new column dint get added to the existing table @Anand Sowmithiran

Comment: you should also call cnxn.commit(), then only such DDL changes will get persisted into the database.

Comment: Alternately, you could enable Auto commit, by setting `autocommit` property to true of the Connection object.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are wondering `autocommit` mentioned above is a `pyodbc` connect parameter.

`conn = pyodbc.connect(sql_server_cnxn_string, autocommit=True)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33308105)